# Converting personal geodatabase .mdb file to .gdb

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase

Is it possible to convert an MS Access personal geodatabase file to a SDE enterprise geodatabase file format? What kind of python scripting would it entail? I need to convert it in such way to maintain consistent geometric/spatial properties for an application.

I have looked for similar questions but to no avail, please direct me to one if I missed it!

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2 on a Windows machine

Comment: You should be able to do this without any scripting.  Just create a new file geodatabase, and by using ArcCatalog you can select all the feature data sets/feature classes in the personal gdb and copy and paste them into the new file gdb.

Comment: I need to take various different personal geodatabases and convert them over to ArcSDE format.

Comment: You just changed the requirements. Your question says geodatabase file format, now you said ArcSDE (enterprise geodatabase). If indeed you're migrating your data into an enterprise geodatabase, use the FC 2 Geodatabase tool referenced in Maksim's answer. It would also be good to clear up your original question.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Feature Class To Geodatabase (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000021000000) tool. This should hopefully do what you need. You can right click the tool and batch export a number of items.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have all the featureclasses you want to convert in a map document, you could just run the [Consolidate Map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Consolidate_Map/0017000000q3000000/) tool on that MXD. Make sure to check the "convert data to file geodatabase option". Inside the output folder will be one or more fgdbs (depending on how many source pgdbs held the original features).

If you don't have an MXD with all the data referenced, @Maksim answer of FC to Geodatabase is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
 This code in the last line won't function. 

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/temp"
print env.workspace

# Set local variables
inFeatures = 'task7.mdb'
print inFeatures
outLocation = 'C:/temp/output.gdb'
print outLocation

# Execute TableToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
```